# Short array and update key as of value[0] and remove unused data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Here is my array so far i am exploding the [category_name] using this php function

```
$query = $this->db->get('payment');

        $result = $query->result();

        // echo '<pre>';print_r($result);

        foreach ($result as $key => $category) {

            $category_sale_data = explode(',', $category->category_name);

            foreach ($category_sale_data as $key => $value) {

                $category->sale_data[] = explode('*', $value);

            }
            
            $newresults[]=$category;
        }
        
        $result=$newresults;

        echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
        die();
```

Here is output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 32459*1500*lab*1,32460*400*lab*1,32461*600*lab*1
            [sale_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 32459
                            [1] => 1500
                            [2] => lab
                            [3] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 32460
                            [1] => 400
                            [2] => lab
                            [3] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 32461
                            [1] => 600
                            [2] => lab
                            [3] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

i want output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 32459*1500*lab*1,32460*400*lab*1,32461*600*lab*1
            [sale_data] => Array
                (
                    [32459] => Array
                        (
                            
                            [0] => 1500
                        )

                    [32460] => Array
                        (
                            [0] =>400
                        )

                    [32461] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 600
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

i need to update records to short array to make it useful for me later. i have tried my best.
I am newbie and learning about php arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the key and the value before to add data in `sale_data` :

```php
foreach ($category_sale_data as $key => $value) {
    [$sale_key, $sale_value] = explode('*', $value);
    $category->sale_data[$sale_key][] = $sale_value;
}
```

Full example - ([livedemo](https://3v4l.org/6ZmQ9))

```php
// Sample data
$category = (object) ['category_name' => '32459*1500*lab*1,32460*400*lab*1,32461*600*lab*1'];
// process
$category_sale_data = explode(',', $category->category_name);
foreach ($category_sale_data as $key => $value) {
    [$sale_key, $sale_value] = explode('*', $value);
    $category->sale_data[$sale_key][] = $sale_value;
}
// display
print_r($category);
```

Output :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [category_name] => 32459*1500*lab*1,32460*400*lab*1,32461*600*lab*1
    [sale_data] => Array
        (
            [32459] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1500
                )
            [32460] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 400
                )
            [32461] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 600
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: thanks for help but it's not working because the sample data is in array not stdClass Object, please edit the answer and make it work with example array so i can check

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='  here [$sale_key, $sale_value] = explode('*', $value);

Comment: you have an old php version : use `list($sale_key, $sale_value) = explode('*', $value);` instead.

Comment: it's working now my php version is not too old it's 7.0 anywhy bundle of thanks

Comment: You're right :) The [short list syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax) as of PHP 7.1.